# Why does Convert.ToInt32 accept IFormatProvider?

Tags: .net, number-formatting, cultureinfo

It makes sense for me to have following overload in Convert class

```
public static double ToDouble(string value, IFormatProvider provider);
```

examples:

```
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToDouble("3223.2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)); // success
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToDouble("3223,2", new CultureInfo("fr-FR"))); // success
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToDouble("3223.2", new CultureInfo("fr-FR"))); // failure
```

But what is an example of using following overload?

```
public static int ToInt32(string value, IFormatProvider provider);
```

Everything fails below:

```
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32("3223.2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32("3223,2", new CultureInfo("fr-FR")));
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32("3223.2", new CultureInfo("fr-FR")));
```

In other words are there any valid string representations of integer (in any culture) which can not be converted to int without specifying IFormatProvider?

Comment: There are other Unicode characters for the digits 1-10 as they appear in other alphabets, for example Arabic.  Perhaps this is related?

Comment: The reason why "everything fails below" is that you're trying to convert a string containing a *floating point* value into an integer value.

Comment: Some cultures uses thousand separators and odd places to place the minus sign.

Comment: can you provide some examples?

Comment: What is the value of `1.000`? One or one thousand? What about `1,000` ? France, Germany, Greece (and others) use `.` as the grouping separator and `,` as the decimal separator

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos as I already pointed out, converting 1.000 and 1,000 to integer fails with FormatException

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use the simple version of Convert.ToInt32 you are still using the overload that takes the readonly CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, as you can see if you look at the [reference source of Convert.ToInt32](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,069d595792a157df)

```
public static int ToInt32(String value) {
    if (value == null)
        return 0;
    return Int32.Parse(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
}
```

The point is, a lot of cultures, custom made or not, could use different characters also for common operations like a conversion and need a proper support structure.

Here an example of an odd use of custom CultureInfo that allow a weird conversion of a string to an integer

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("it-IT");
ci.NumberFormat.NegativeSign = "@";

int number = Convert.ToInt32("@10", ci);
Console.WriteLine(number);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Besides "weird custom-made" cultures, what can be the real-world examples when one should specify IFormatProvider?

Comment: I have never seen the necessity for this, but perhaps my views are limited to my experience mostly with the same culture info. I recognize however that in different part of the world there is this necessity. For example imagine if your software needs to parse a text file coming from such a community that uses the @ as negative symbol.